# Выполнение нескольких событий при подтверждении одной html формы

Tags: html

Всем привет! 
Подскажите пожалуйста, может ли **html форма** выполнить **два события** сразу по одному нажатию на кнопку **submit**, т.е. по сути требуется сделать так, чтобы форма выполнила свою какую-то основную функцию и одновременно с этим (короче говоря синхронно), отправила данные в другую форму и плюс эти данные которые передала другой форме параллельно записала в файл. Помогите пожалуйста, кто знает как это сделать, не обязательно исходным кодом, может кто-то алгоритм видит.

Comment: Кодом мы не помогаем, пора бы уяснить.

    var f = document.forms[0]; 
    f.addEventListener("submit", functionUno, false);
    f.addEventListener("submit", functionDos, false);

Comment: Минус то за что? Я же написал, что не обязательно кодом делится, я и сам могу код написать...

Comment: оформляйте как ответ, поставлю плюсик :) Спасибо

Comment: серъёзно? не сарказм? О__о

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> может кто-то алгоритм видит

1. Закешировать данные формы
2. Сабмит формы
3. Передать закешированные данные другой форме
4. Записать закешированные данные в файл

Answer (score 1):

А не проще все описанные действия сделать в одной функции? Или на худой конец просто вызвать вторую функцию в начале первой?

```
function firstFunc(){
        secondFunc();
        /*
         Дальше основной код первой функции
        */

}

function secondFunc(){
        // ...
}
```

P.S.

> плюс эти данные которые передала другой форме параллельно записала в файл.

Вы точно про html формы пишите? Помниться работа с FS былf возможнf только в IE через ActiveX да и то вроде бы функционал неполноценный был